# Can interarrival time be used with anylogic schedule block?

Tags: simulation, modeling, schedule, anylogic, agent

I'm trying to model a production sequence in anylogic where orders should come in with an interarrival time of `normal(8,105)` seconds. These orders should come in every week day between 11 am and 2 pm (3 hour window).

I tried to implement this with the `Schedule` block in anylogic but this only allows me to define a rate per hour. **Is there a way to do this with interarrival time**?

Also the agents that arrive at 1:59 pm should also be processed even if it takes until after 2 pm. **Is there a way to calculate the mean working time per day** (the time from the generation of the first agent by the `source` block until the last generated agent enters the `sink` block)?

Thank you all in advance!

Comment: To my understanding 8 stands for the standard deviation and 105 for the mean in this case. How will this generate negative values? Sorry if I'm missing someting.

Comment: Sorry my bad, misunderstood.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use the `getHour()` function and dispose of the agents if hour is not between 11 and 14. And inside the source you don't need to do anything special. If it even arrives at 11.59 pm it will be processed.

[image]

Comment: Thank you I will most definitely try this approach. Do you also have an idea how to calculate the mean time there are agents contained in the system? How can I calculate this over a period of multiple working days?

Comment: Glad that my answer was useful. Please feel free to upvote and accept as answer so that others can also benefit. You can use this approach for calculating the time in system (also their means): https://anylogic.help/library-reference-guides/process-modeling-library/time-in-system.html